# Prove logic equivalence

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Show that $∀xP(x) ∨ ∀xQ(x)$ and $∀x∀y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))$, where all quantifiers have the
same nonempty domain, are logically equivalent. (The new variable y is used to
combine the quantification's correctly.)

I'm not sure what the y is there for, and how to go about solving this. I know that I can prove they're logically equivalent by proving that they imply each other but how do I do that?

Comment: The reason the $y$ is there is because you've miscopied the second expression. It should be $\forall x \forall y(P(x)  ∨ Q(y))$.

Comment: Fixed it, thank you. But I still am not sure about how to go about solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P(x)$ is not bounded by $\forall y$. So $P(x)$ can be moved out of $∀y$, i.e.
$$
∀y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))\iff P(x) ∨∀yQ(y)
$$
And $Q(y)$ is not bounded by $\forall x$. So $∀yQ(y)$ can be moved out of $∀x$, i.e.
$$
∀x(P(x) ∨∀y Q(y))\iff ∀xP(x) ∨∀y Q(y)\iff ∀xP(x) ∨∀x Q(x)
$$
So there is
$$
∀x∀y(P(x) ∨ Q(y))\iff∀x(P(x) ∨∀y Q(y))\iff ∀xP(x)∨∀x Q(x)
$$

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!